# Converting txt to xml through XSLT

Tags: java, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0, saxon

I got an use case and exploring XSLT. I have text file with tab delimited data.
as following -

```
column1 column2 column3
name1    age1    addr1
name2    age2    addr2
name3    age3    addr3
```

Could somebody please help me how to transform this text to following xml using XSLT 1.0 & XSLT 2.0 .

```
<table>
  <row id=1> 
    <column1>name1</column1>
    <column2>age1</column2>
    <column3>addr1</column3>
  </row>
  <row id=2> 
    <column1>name2</column1>
    <column2>age2</column2>
    <column3>addr2</column3>
  </row>
  <row id=3> 
    <column1>name3</column1>
    <column2>age3</column2>
    <column3>addr3</column3>
  </row>
</table>
```

Comment: From what I know XSLT is used to format a XML document, not the inverse.

Comment: You cannot use XSLT to do this.You can only do this if you have a clear format or use heuristics.

Answer (score 3):

Please find a tab-separated-values (TSV) text file to XML converter using XSLT 2 here:

http://www.CraneSoftwrights.com/resources/#csv

It is designed to be used either standalone or imported into another stylesheet.

Comment: You should really divulge the fact that this is your company/product. Otherwise this just seems a little spammy. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers

Comment: Forgive me, but I don't see how it is "spammy" if it is *directly* pertinent to the question and it is a free developer resource.  If I have offended anyone, I apologize for having done so.  Oh, and I have fully divulged my affiliation and my credentials in my SO profile, so I'm unclear why a disclaimer would need to be duplicated in every post.

Comment: By just looking at this answer all I see is a link to your company product without an explanation of what it is or how to use it by showing a code example. Without that I just feel that at least a mention that you own this site would make it appear less like spam. I didn't mean to be offensive I was just concerned this post might be removed and was hoping it could be revised. That's why I included the meta question that this practice tends to be frowned upon by the community.